# How to make DevServer put all assemblies in one folder?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, iis-express, vs-devserver

I need to config IIS-Express (or DevServer) to put all output assembly files in one place.
Now DevServer copies each dll to its own folder like:

*C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3df2e06f\587c7c63\assembly\dl3\fea77c7a\42e614aee75dcc01"*

I need this to enumerate assemblies, and load plugins.
Three month ago I managed to find special key to app.config, which helped.

Does enyone know this *magic app.config key*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found:

```
<system.web>
   <hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="false" />
</system.web>
```